# File format name downloads in foreign language not supported on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, google-chrome, globalization

As i am trying to achieve to download a file from azure based hosted website which shows the following.
[image: Azure website]
it has a Russian name on the file, now as i download it shows in some machine language as given in the above image as i am using chrome to download the file.

Now as i am downloading the image on my local machine from my local project it gives me that language downloaded file, here is a sample below.
[image: Local machine]
as you can see the file name is same in that language.

The client had made some changes in web config for language globalization on azure but didn't work.

Please suggest me if anyone has any solution. Thank you

Comment: I have tested all the sample file names you provided(`- room__комната , В соответствии , Pic_歡迎每天發掘更多精彩內容 `), and you can also see the effect from the screenshot in the answer and the code is also provided in Answer.

Comment: Does my solution help you? I look forward to receiving a reply.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

My previous answer was correct. I will show you all of my test code now. You can write a demo test that has completely solved your problem.

[image]

Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Downloadasp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
        public void DownloadOperation()
        {
            // Original file name
            string fileName = "- room__комната.jpg";
            string strFilePath = "/upload/image/20180307/";
            // Server Path
            string filepath = Server.MapPath(strFilePath)+fileName;
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filepath);
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            // Solve garbled file names
            if (Request.UserAgent.Contains("MSIE") || Request.UserAgent.Contains("msie"))
            {
                // If the client uses Microsoft Internet Explorer, encoding is required
                fileName = ToHexString(fileName);
            }
            // The core part of the problem solving
            // Already tested
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
            Response.WriteFile(fileInfo.FullName);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Encode non-English characters in the string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="s"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string ToHexString(string s)
        {
            char[] chars = s.ToCharArray();
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int index = 0; index < chars.Length; index++)
            {
                bool needToEncode = NeedToEncode(chars[index]);
                if (needToEncode)
                {
                    string encodedString = ToHexString(chars[index]);
                    builder.Append(encodedString);
                }
                else
                {
                    builder.Append(chars[index]);
                }
            }

            return builder.ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///Specifies whether a character should be encoded
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="chr"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static bool NeedToEncode(char chr)
        {
            string reservedChars = "$-_.+!*'(),@=&";

            if (chr > 127)
                return true;
            if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(chr) || reservedChars.IndexOf(chr) >= 0)
                return false;

            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Encode non-English strings
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="chr"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static string ToHexString(char chr)
        {
            UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] encodedBytes = utf8.GetBytes(chr.ToString());
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int index = 0; index < encodedBytes.Length; index++)
            {
                builder.AppendFormat("%{0}", Convert.ToString(encodedBytes[index], 16));
            }
            return builder.ToString();
        }


        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
   }
}
```

**PRIVIOUS**

The core code statement to solve the garbled file name.

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(filename, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

Sample Code:

```
System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo("filename.xls");
Response.Clear();
// Solve garbled file names
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(file.Name));

Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "application/application/octet-stream";
Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
Response.End();
Response.Flush();
Response.Clear();
```

Comment: I have tried this as well only works when I start my project on local machine
but when I publish the code over azure it still shows the same issue.

Comment: Can you give me a sample filename，I can try it by myself later.

Comment: I want this a little sooner, the client has given the pressure, kindly request to you please try to get the solution out a little bit. the sample name are given below:- room__комната , В соответствии , Pic_歡迎每天發掘更多精彩內容

Comment: Does my solution work for you? Do you need further help with this issue?

Comment: Thanks for the help mate, actually we don't have any azure access and we communicate with client . if client will give azure access then we can test your solution. otherwise we discuss with client regarding your solution. if it works then i will update you. Thank you

Comment: @MohdAlam Okay, if you have an Azure subscription yourself, you can write a demo and test it yourself. My solution is to reproduce the problem you encounter first, and then solve it, there should be no problem. It is recommended that your customers test it first.