# How to get unicode string from http request header in ASP.NET Core 6 similar to ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have two similar controllers in ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core 6 projects that both run through IIS. When I request the first one, the custom http request header containing unicode characters is parsed correctly:

[image]

When I request the second one, instead of unicode characters, I get question marks (65533-symbol):

[image]

How can I get the same result in the second case as in the first?

Comment: Can you show the code you use to call an api, pls? I tried to test your code but got "Request headers must contain only ASCII characters."

Comment: @Serge

curl -X GET http://localhost:4809/api/ContrName/ProposalChangeFrom?id=10 -v --ntlm -u  login:pass --header "Description:ПопыткаОтказа111"

_("ntlm" part is auth part)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

After consulting the official documentation, I regret to tell you that adding Bulgarian to the Http Header directly is not supported. (I googled it and found that it might be Bulgarian language)

[image]

You can [check the not supported language in Endoding first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/actions-reference/web#downloadfromweb).

#### Workaround

You can use `encodeURIComponent()` method to encode `Пример` before you  send httprequest.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Please use `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode` method to encode the characters.

```
var desc22=HttpContext.Request.Headers["Description"];
string desc22_ncode1 = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
return ...
```

**Related Post**

[1. File format name downloads in foreign language not supported on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61747972/file-format-name-downloads-in-foreign-language-not-supported-on-azure/61748648#61748648)

[2. Encoding issues in Azure WebApps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64227444/encoding-issues-in-azure-webapps/64345309#64345309)

Comment: It just gave me 
`%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd111`

Comment: @AlMaslov Please recreate two simple method which can reproduce the issue in our side.

Comment: https://github.com/MaslovRG/RequestHeaders

Comment: Right, http headers should be encoded in ISO-8859-1, but client / server implementations vary.

Comment: I have the request returned by external service. My curl request just mimics this wrong behavior. It's main problem. Looks like I'll have to make Asp Net MVC layer to process it correctly.

Comment: @AlMaslov Yes, in my screenshot, postman pointed out the cause of the problem. So before sending the request, we need to encode these special characters.